# Logging Transactions to Azure Table, then summarizing in a SQL Azure database for reporting

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, nosql

I have an application using SQL Azure (business Tier) for data storage.  It is essentially logging transactions 24/7, currently handling 8-10 thousand a day.  Each transaction is normalized when logged, with potential new keys needing to be created to support the normalization.  We end up with each transaction taking 1-2 seconds to log.

Every 30 minutes or so we summarize the transaction data for many reports grouped by the hour, day, week, and month.  This operation takes between 2-4 minutes.

We are basically performing at a reasonable level right now, however the load is set to increase and we are considering some options for handling the increase. Early testing shows we are not going to be handle the increased load (10x) with our current architecture.

We are considering changing to a NoSQL data solution for the transaction logging, possibly Azure Table Storage.  This portion seems relatively strait forward.

Once in Table Storage (or other NoSQL storage), what are the best approaches for summarizing the data and moving into our SQL Azure database for reporting?  Currently all the summary logic is built in to the database in stored procedures based on the normalized transactions.

Is there a way to load data from Table Storage to Azure in a batch mode which we could then summarize?  Should we be moving the summary logic into a .NET service/application that would read from the transaction log, summarize the data, and then write that to our SQL Azure database?

We haven't found any good examples of using Table Storage and SQL Azure together, everything seems to be a comparison of the two.

Essentially we are looking for some guidance or examples on similar scenarios.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You already have some reporting infrastructure built on top of SQL Azure which you want to reuse. In that case, your solution of building an application that reads raw data from the Azure Tables, aggregates data and inserts results into SQL Azure seems to be the appropriate solution.

Partition key (pk) and row key(rk)  selection can significantly influence the performance of read/write operations to Azure tables.  The selection of PK, RK and other table properties depends on how you are going to use the data, your dominant query and application behavior. The storage team blob (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx) has guidance on this for common scenarios

Note: You may already know this, but there are Azure SDK's in languages other than .NET that  you can use. If possible, you may also want to deploy your application in the same data centre as the Azure Table and SQL Azure for better performance